# can't add the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use ZipFile class but can't figure out how to add namespace properly.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

gives

> ErrorCS0117    'ZipFile' does not contain a definition for 'CreateFromDirectory'
>
> ErrorCS0117    'ZipFile' does not contain a definition for 'ExtractToDirectory'

I have added the

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;
```

which results in

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression;

added the assembly references to

```
System.IO.Compression

Assembly System.IO.Compression
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.IO.Compression.dll

System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

    Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
```

tried to install/uninstall packages with NuGet. Rebuild, even restart the PC.

Nothing seems to be working. The current version of .Net in VS is 4.7

Comment: Don't conflate assembly names and namespaces. The namespace is `System.IO.Compression` even when the *assembly name* is `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Comment: I still can't reach to the desired methods in that case

Comment: If you've removed the useless `using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;` line, you do have the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` assembly referenced, and you're still seeing this error, the most obvious suspect is that you've named one of your classes `ZipFile` and that's being picked up in preference to the one in the `Compression` namespace. What happens if you write `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);`?

Comment: You are right. It conflicted with `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip` which has the same class name and which assembly I tried to use before. After deleting all unnecessary assemblies and namespaces I managed to run the program correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Please add reference `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` 
Screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly from the Framework.